# tkinter - Large amount of delay/lag when scrolling

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and will paypal anyone £5 who can successfully answer this for me :). When i scroll my tkinter frame it will 'clump' all my widgets together and take some time before they all get put back into place, however if i use the arrows on my scrollbar there doesnt seem to be any problems with the widgets in the frame (i.e they all arrange correctly and everything looks as normal). basically in a summary there is a large amount of scroll delay and i really need some help!.

I am using python 3.9 and tkinter version 8.6

here is a small snippet ( i am retrieving data from a local database using SQlite)

```
root = tk.Tk()
container = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
rowe=0



for i in range(100):
    ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='hello').grid(row=rowe, column=1)
    ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='hello').grid(row=rowe, column=2)
    ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random').grid(row=rowe, column=3)
    ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random').grid(row=rowe, column=4)
    ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random').grid(row=rowe, column=5)
    ttk.Button(scrollable_frame, text='button').grid(row=rowe, column=6)
    rowe=rowe+1

container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: This website is free for a reason. Saying that you will pay people isn't going to change the amount/quality of the answers you get.

Comment: Also can you please provide a minimalistic working example to show the problem. Also please add the python/tcl version that you are using

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry i just wanted to show some appreciation to someone if they were able to solve my problem also didnt realise this community replied so quickly its amazing - sorry if i offended anyone

Comment: @BryanOakley - it is hard to as it seems a small minimalistic example means there is no lag when scrolling.

Comment: Since the data doesn't likely matter, please provide an example that doesn't rely on a database which we don't have access to.

Comment: @BryanOakley it can be any data - for the text of each widget you could put 'hello' for all of them and i still get this weird lag. Thanks for your response

Comment: If that's the case, please update your example to do that.

Comment: @BryanOakley All done - hope to hear back. Cheers

Comment: @BryanOakley Just have to add the lag/time it takes for the widgets to 'refresh' in the frame or render in isnt nearly as bad as it is with my whole code - i am have multiple 'pages' using the .lift() command and there only seems to be lag whenever i run the entire code. I am wondering if tkinter isnt fast enough as there are too many things going on in the background or what im rlly not top sure

Comment: If we can't easily duplicate the problem, we're probably not going to be able to help. Though, tkinter isn't designed to be managing thousands of widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley is there a better library you suggest using?